# How to make a window in Bevy that is a transparent overlay that doesn’t interfere with the underlying applications (doesn’t block mouse, keyboard etc)

Tags: rust, window, cross-platform, bevy, wgpu-rs

I would like to create a bevy window that:
Has no background
Has no window decoration
Is always on top
Doesn’t interfere with input to the underlying window.

I have done some research, and I think that on windows you can set a value called “input transparency” on the window, which defines if windows underneath can also receive input. Bevy-rs is a simplistic rust library, so I don’t know if I can make this work very easily.
Is there a way I could make this work? Will I have to modify the wgpu-rs underlying code? Or will I have to use another game engine apart from Bevy?

Bevy version: 0.8.0

Comment: It doesn't look to me like bevy or winit (the crate supporting bevy's windowing) support this.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with no modifications to Bevy.

Here's how to do it with Bevy 0.12

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy::window::WindowLevel;

let window = Window {
    // Enable transparent support for the window
    transparent: true,
    decorations: false,
    window_level: WindowLevel::AlwaysOnTop,
    cursor: Cursor {
        // Allow inputs to pass through to apps behind this app.
        hit_test: false,
        ..default()
    },
    ..default()
};

App::new()
    // Make it render background as transparent
    .insert_resource(ClearColor(Color::NONE))
    .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(WindowPlugin {
        primary_window: Some(window),
        ..default()
    }))
    .run()
```

Bevy only sends inputs when the window has focused though, so depending on your app, you might want to use something like https://crates.io/crates/bevy_global_input (Hasn't been updated to Bevy 0.12 yet unfortunately ☹️)

Comment: This is slightly out of date. The window should now use `window_level: WindowLevel::AlwaysOnTop` instead of `always_on_top: true`.

Comment: @ed__Thanks for letting me know! I updated it to work with Bevy 0.12